# JavaScript Confirm Leave Once User Interacts with Object in Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe

I currently have a webpage in a format similar to this, with a sidebar and iframes with sources pointing to other pages on my website.

[image]

I have the following code to offer user a confirm box for if they wish to leave the page:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return 'All unsaved data will be lost.';
};
```

In the iframes, I have various HTML elements, such as textfields, input boxes, buttons, etc. I don't want the user to get the `onbeforeunload` function **unless** they have clicked on one of these input elements first.

Of course, I could go in and code each textfield, button, etc, manually using by creating a variable such as `shouldPopup`, then using `onclick` to set `shouldPopup` to `TRUE`, and finally using an `onbeforeunload` if statement, but this is inconvenient and, if I were to perhaps make more changes in the future, I would potentially have to go in and modify each element one by one again.

What is a better way to get the same results? Any input as to how to simplify the code is greatly appreciated! :)

**Update:**

Some more information about my Iframes. I am using the jQuery library for some basic functions (nothing fancy). There's quite a bit of PHP in them, as well as a few database requests, but nothing out of the ordinary. Hopefully this information is helpful to anyone looking to make any suggestions

Comment: In my opinion this is the most straight forward way to archieve this. I assume you're not using some model/view tooling like [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/#) in your iFrame's forms, so monitoring the state and toggeling a flag is the simplest way to go. Could you please add some details: (shortened) code you're using in your iFrames, libraries you're using (like jQuery, Backbone.js etc.). It will help understanding your setup.

Comment: Updated my post. If there's anything else I can add, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change too much of your code, I think toggeling a flag is OK. The following is a simple, pragmatic approach.

Example form:

```
<input type="text" class="form" ...>
<input type="text" class="form" ...>
<select class="form" ...>
   <option value=""></option>
   ...
</select>
```

Monitor changes in both iFrames:

```
(function(){
  // This can be optimized to check against saved values on blur
  $("body").on("change", ".form", function(evt){
    window.top.$(window.top).trigger("change-form"); // trigger custom event in parent page
  });
}());
```

Parent page:

```
(function(){
  var dirty = false
  $(window).on("change-form", function(){
    dirty = true;
  });

  window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    // Notify user only if forms are dirty
    return dirty ? 'All unsaved data will be lost.' : undefined;
  };
}());
```

This code is braindump, it's untested.

**Note:** If your pages are served from different domains than the parent page you'll run into cross site scripting issues. In that case you're not able to access the parent page's Javascript. Then you have to use [postMessage()](http://css.dzone.com/news/postmessage-html5-send) to send messages to your parent page's domain.

---

I'd suggest you to take a look at [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/):

- https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/wiki/Tutorials%2C-blog-posts-and-example-sites
- http://backbonejs.org/#examples

## Edit 1:

Backbone can help you managing the state of your form. In Backbone a [Model](http://backbonejs.org/#Model) will represent your form data. A [View](http://backbonejs.org/#View) - representing your form (form's inputs) - is bound to that Model. It will monitor your form fields and [set()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) attributes on the model. A Backbone Model has its own state, you can check if the form has chnaged using e.g. the [changed()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changed) method. Separating Model and View in your application is always a good idea, it helps separating the responsibilities.

I just wanted to give you another idea.

## Edit 2:

Fixed the code that triggers an event in the top window. I was not sure if `$(window.top)` works. It does not work. I'm not sure why. I've tested it and this code is correct:

```
window.top.$(window.top). ...
```

I've updated the above code.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response! +1 I will consider your approach. I don't think it will involve too much modification for me to my existing code

Comment: My pleasure! Note, that you maybe have to play around with the event firing (`trigger`) within the iFrame. The monitoring of the form fields is very simple. For example, it will mark the form dirty if you change a value from say "abc" to "cba" back to "abc": the form has not changed but is marked dirty. But as most applications (known to me) treat this as "dirty", I think it's OK for your case too.

Comment: I've updated my code: `$(window.top)` is not enough, this is necessary: `window.top.$(window.top)`.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you're looking for (essentially) a dirty flag (like here on SO uses). Essentially, since this is supplemental to design, so keep the script apart from UI and just use some sort of selector to grab all the elements that could potentially be changed and bind an event that simply monitors and changes the dirty flag accordingly.

For the sake of brevity, here's a jQuery version:

```
var isDirty = false;
$(':input').on('change', function(e){
  isDirty = true;
});
$(window).on('beforeunload',function(e){
  if (isDirty){
    // Alert th euser there's unfinished changes
  }
});
```

Very simple, and keeps the script separated. Also, if these are your child windows, you could reference the `window.parent` and pass the flag up to the main view (if you so chose).